# cuda kernel not executing or returning an error

Tags: gpu, cuda

I have some cuda code running through some FFTs and other math operations, which works on blocks of 2^n as requested by the user.  The code works well when first run, but after running long enough it starts to fail.  Eventually it will get to the point where if I run any block size larger then 2^ll I get no data back (all zeros).  I've done some testing by modifying the kernel code and from what I can tell the kernel is not executing.  I'm trying to figure out why my code stops producing data after multiple iterations on large block sizes.

The issue looks at first glance to be memory leak.  I know I have to run multiple iterations of the processing to cause an error.  At first only large block sizes will stop working, but as I run more iterations smaller block sizes will start to fail as well.  The reason I'm not certain the issue is memory is that my code will work for a block size lower then 2^11 regardless of how many iterations I run.  If this was a simple memory leak I would have expected the symptoms to get progressively worse until I couldn't access any memory on the card.

I've also noticed that larger block sizes (roughly equivalent to the amount of memory each thread uses) tend to cause the program to fail sooner.  Increasing the number of blocks processed (ie number of Cuda threads) doesn't seem to have an affect on when the code starts to fail.

as far as I can tell no error code is being returned, the kernel doesn't appear to execute at all.

Can anyone suggest what my be causing this issue?  I would settle for any insight in how to debug code running on the GPU or to monitor GPU memory availability.

Comment: `cuda-gdb` and check your return statuses

Comment: cuda 4.0 ? or older versions ?

Comment: I should be using the newest version of cuda. also I got sloppy with my terminology.  I am increasing my block size, not my thread size, already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need more computation done, bump up your grid size and not your thread block size. To quote the CUDA programming guide 3.0 on pg. 8, "On current GPUs, a thread block may contain up to 512 
threads."

This means that threadIdx.x * threadIdx.y * threadIdx.z <= 512 at all times. If you maintain that invariant, do things work?